# How to modify comments in C# Designer.cs file

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I'm currently making a custom control, and some of the properties are generating these weird blank comments when VS writes the Designer.cs file. Example:

```
// 
// myControl
// 
this.myControl.Name = "myControl";
this.myControl.Property = 30;
this.myControl.OtherProperty = 20;
// 
// 
// 
this.myControl.Options1.Name = null;
this.myControl.Options1.Option = "example";
// 
// 
// 
this.myControl.Options2.Name = null;
this.myControl.Options2.SomeProperty = 50;
this.myControl.Options2.SomeEvent += new System.EventHandler(this.myControl_Options2_SomeEvent);
this.myControl.OtherProperty = 10;
```

Does anybody know what's causing these blank comments? I'd prefer no comments at all, but if I can at least have the name "myControl.Options1" shown that would be acceptable.

Here is the rough structure of my classes (although very simplified):

```
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class Options : IComponent
// I implement IComponent so this class appears in the Properties window nicely. Not sure why exactly it works though.
{

    #region Implement IComponent

    public ISite Site { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Nothing needs to be disposed
        Disposed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public event EventHandler Disposed;

    #endregion
}

public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    #region Options

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Options Options1 { get; private set; }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Options Options2 { get; private set; }

    public MyControl
    {
        Options1 = new Options();
        Options2 = new Options();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Any ideas would be very helpful! I haven't been able to find this problem anywhere else online. My assumption is that I'm misusing the IComponent interface, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: You shouldn´t care for those auto-generated comments as they don´t do anything and are introduced just for the sake of readability. However feel free to simply delete them.

Comment: It's usually best to let generated code live out its life in quiet isolation.

Comment: @HimBromBeere No, don't delete them, any edit you make will get overwritten if you make any changes to the form. It's generated code, just ignore it.

Comment: Agreed, leave them be.  Designer code is no place to exercise OCD clean-ups...you'll go mad.

Comment: This control is intended to be used by other developers, thus readability is exactly what I'm trying to achieve because it looks like a mess right now.

Comment: It's perfectly readable as it is right now, but you don't, and shouldn't ever even open it. Just close that file and pretend you never saw it.

Comment: @AnotherProgrammer *.Designer.cs is not intended to be used by other developers. It is machine-generated and machine-read.

Comment: That doesn't mean other developers should never look at it. I personally find it very helpful when debugging to look through the designer code. I also frequently have to delete event handler subscriptions if I am removing an event.

Comment: If they're competent to mess with what's in there, they don't need any comments and they won't hold it against you if you didn't waste your time optimizing comment generation in a file that's meant to be more or less opaque. I mean, I'm not saying it's not an interesting question, to find out how to control the comment generation -- just that in practical terms it's a very low priority.

Comment: I agree it's low priority, but it would be nice nonetheless. I was hoping it would be a quick fix.

Comment: I'm sorry to disagree, but any dev competent enough, wouldn't even open that file, let alone care about the comments. The only time it's useful is if you are getting compile errors about missing controls because it got out of sync somehow, and even then all you do is jiggle the form to regenerate it.

Comment: You've never deleted an event handler in the main code before? You can't even open the Designer in that case, you have to go delete the line in the designer file. I don't know why people shy away from the inner workings, if you know what you're doing it can be beneficial, and also educational.

Comment: OK, I'll give you the bit about the event handler, that is a bit of a PITA. But I wouldn't exactly call it "inner workings". It's just defining controls and properties.

Comment: @DavidG Never say never. I did it a few times in my winforms days. Very, very rarely, because I broke things that way early on, and there's very rarely any need -- but not never.

Answer (score 3):

Those comments are automatically generated and have no impact on the output binary. When you compile, they'll all be dropped, so you needn't worry about bloat or anything like that. For maintainability, other developers should be directed to the designer, not the outputted code. Their edits won't be preserved if someone makes a change in the designer.

I suggest ignoring what's actually emitted by the designer entirely. It's not really meant to be edited- useful to view what source actually gets created from the designer, though.

Answer (score 1):

That is the default behavior of the ComponentCodeDomSerializer when serializing the component name.

You can derive from the ComponentCodeDomSerializer and override Serialize, call the base class, then remove the CodeCommentStatement objects from the returned CodeStatementCollection.

Comment: Thanks, I actually found a slightly simpler solution too thanks to this. I simply added [DesignerSerializer(typeof(CodeDomSerializer), typeof(CodeDomSerializerBase))] to my class and it stopped treating it like a component for serialization.

Comment: ComponentCodeDomSerializer does more than adding comments.. But probably good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Nevermind, this doesn't work. It seemed like it was working until I used the control elsewhere and the problem came back up.**

I found that adding the following attribute to my options class worked for me:

```
[ToolboxItem(false)]
[DesignerSerializer(typeof(CodeDomSerializer), typeof(CodeDomSerializerBase))]
public class Options : IComponent
{ 
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have linked, looks a bit weird. Well the commenting system works as follow:
Your auto generated designer 'Methods' will be signed with an xml comment which describes their behavior. 
It also writes comments to define Which control properties are being set on the current block. 
in your case:

```
// 
// myControl
// 
this.myControl.Name = "myControl";
this.myControl.Property = 30;
this.myControl.OtherProperty = 20;
```

the 'myControl' means there is a control named 'myControl' that the following lines are setting it's properties.
As u said u r gonna ship this control. I think event these short nonsense comments are useful.